# The placement of a one place predicate in a conditional from a sentence of English

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

I was having some confusion about where to place the 'N' predicate in the conditional below.

My guess was to keep it with what it was grouped with in the english sentence, however if it is not placed with the 'D' , I feel that if I read it out loud it doesn't make as much sense. Are both forms equivalent:

The dictionary:

D = a 2 place predicate meaning -divisable by-;;;
N = a one place predicate meaning - number-;;;
O = a one place predicate meaning - odd-;;;
t = -two-

The question: A number is odd if it is not divisible by two:

Is it: ∀x[-D(xt)→(N(x) & O(x))]

or is it: Is it: ∀x[(N(x) & -D(xt))→O(x)]

and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the latter, $\forall x\,[(N(x) \land \neg D(x,t))\to O(x)]$. Why? Because the statement is: for all numbers $x$, if $x$ is not divisible by $2$ then $x$ is odd, which can be rendered by the first order sentence shown, using your predicates $N, D, O$ and constant $t$.